# map<A, set<A*>> vs. set<A> where A holds set of A*

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'd like to represent a graph in C++.

I'm parsing my input data which are (1) the nodes and (2) the connections between the nodes.

My question is about the data structure to hold the nodes and the connections:

My first approach was a kind of linked list I knew from C but using STL containers:
A `class A` holding the name of the node and a `std::set<A*>` to store pointers to the connected nodes.
Something like this (not compilable, just a draft of the idea):

```
class A
{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::set<A*> links;

    public:
        // constr., destr., getter, setter, ...
};
```

My second thought was a `std::map<A, std::set<A*> >` or even `std::map<A, std::vector<A*> >` which in my opinion would be the better approach in this case.

Of course the `class A` in this case would hold only the name:

```
class A
{
    private:
        std::string name;

    public:
        // constr., destr., getter, setter, ...
};
```

My graph is filled once with data, no delete/insert/update operations will be applied after the initialisation.

If there is a better data structure approach I did not mention, feel free to enlighten me :)

Comment: If you are allowed to use Boost in your project, I would give a try to the [BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) (Boost Graph Library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach seems more economical:

```
class A
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<A*> links;
}
```

The reasons:

1. map< A, vector > would have to hold a copy of A (as the key), thus bloating memory requirements, especially if the names are long and descriptive.
2. When traversing the nodes you know the current A at any given time, and have direct access to the set/vector of links; with the map you'd have to look up the set/vector of links, which would be a waste of time.

Comment: And how about using smart pointers? Talking about `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A> >` in particular.